# I have updated my android studio version from 2.2.2 to 2.2.3, after updates I getting two errors in build gradle files

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have updated my android studio 2.2.2 to 2.2.3 then I am getting the errors :

```
  android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '25.0.1'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.atritechnocrat.banana"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
   testInstrumentationRunner"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
}
```

Error Information:

```
  Information:Gradle tasks [clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
Error:com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ResourceException: Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
Error:Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
Error:com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 38.615 secs
Information:6 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

How to solve this?

Comment: same happened to me also. Reinstall helped me